# Pauli matrices duality

Tags: linear-algebra

Pauli matrices satisfy
$$
\sigma_i \sigma^{\dagger}_j = \delta_{ij} \sigma_0 + I \epsilon_{ijk}\sigma_k\,,
$$
with $I$ being the imaginary unit.
Can one construct a set of three complex-valued $2\times 2$ matrices $a_i$, $i=1,2,3$, such that
$$
a_i a^{\dagger}_j = \delta_{ij} \sigma_0 - I \epsilon_{ijk}\sigma_k\,?
$$
If not, is it possible for matrices with dimension $2\times N$, with $N>2$?

**Upd:** There is no requirement that matrices $a$ should be self-adjoint.

Comment: Normally  Pauli matrices are selfadjoint and  there is an  $ i \epsilon_{ijk}$ Renumber them $\sigma_{1,2,3} \to \sigma_{ 1,3,2}$

Comment: @RolandF Nope, it doesn't work. Because I have \sigma in the right hand side, not a's.

Comment: And where did the imaginary unit get lost in $\sigma_1 \sigma_2 = i \sigma_3$?

Comment: @RolandF Sorry, my misprint, just fixed it.